# Bootstrap tabbable anchors in sidebar.php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I consider myself intermediate with css, beginner at php, but a nunce with js :/

For my question I am using the basic bootstrap formats and have created a header.php, footer.php, body.php and sidebar.php

Header.php contains all the top nav as well as links to css.

footer.php contains

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
```

body.php contains the main body as well as specific nav links for the page to go into the sidebar.

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="tabbable">
       <div class = "row"> 
        <div class="span8 pull-right">
         <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="thing1">
            <p>about this thing1</p>
          </div><!--end tab-pane-->
          <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="thing2">
            <p>about this thing2</p> 
          </div><!--end tab-pane-->
         </div><!--end tab-content-->
        </div><!--end span8-->

     <!--sidebar info --> 
       <?php 
        $sidebar_nav = "<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked' id='tabs' data-tabs='tabs'>
        <li><a href='#thing1' data-toggle='tab'>Thing 1 >></a></li>
        <li><a href='#thing2' data-toggle='tab'>Thing 2 >></a></li>
        </ul>";
        include "sidebar.php";
       ?> 
     <!-- end sidebar-->

     </div><!--end tabbable-->
    </div><!--end row-->
   </div><!--end container-->
    <!--end main body-->
```

Sidebar.php contains

```
    <div class="span4">
     <div class="well-small">
      <div class="pull-right">
       <?php echo $sidebar_nav;?> 
      </div><!--end pull-right-->   
     </div><!--end well-small -->
    </div><!-- end span4 -->
```

I have played about putting the following code at the bottom of the body.php page as well as in the footer after the script links.

```
       <script>
         $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
     $(this).tab('show');
     });
       </script>
```

I have had the li's class active and have recently taken them out.

What happens is the thing2 block is hidden, clicking on the thing2 link in the side bar does   nothing! What am i doing wrong? It is not switching from thing1 to thing2.

Please help!

Comment: I see you include `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`. Those 2 files are actually the same, but the .min has been minified (=whitespaces are removed to reduce file size) so it is faster to download. You don't need to include them both.

Comment: I added it because someone on here recommended the OP to include it as well and it worked for him. Haha! I'll try anything at this stage!

Answer (score 1):

After a month of going crazy, I found the problem was due to type="text/javascript** unclosed "
Such a newb mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the absolute answer, but a few things I've noticed:

1 - footer.php contains an open  at the bottom of the file.   Remove that line.

2 - You have characters that need to use the HTML entity value instead.  Otherwise, it could be seen as part of an HTML tag.

Change:

```
<li><a href='#thing1' data-toggle='tab'>Thing 1 >></a></li>
<li><a href='#thing2' data-toggle='tab'>Thing 2 >></a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href='#thing1' data-toggle='tab'>Thing 1 &gt;&gt;</a></li>
<li><a href='#thing2' data-toggle='tab'>Thing 2 &gt;&gt;</a></li>
```

Comment: I have changed >> to &gt;&gt; The Footer open tag was the beginning of the #tabs script which I'll edit. Still no change though.